# Moose construct objects from single arguments

Tags: perl, moose, type-constraints

I've been dabbling with Moose for about seven months and Perl only slightly longer, but can't figure out how you can construct several attributes in a class by just supplying one argument for each, instead of a whole hashref of them. I've searched the documentation and the web extensively, but I'm either looking for the wrong words or missing something.

I've adapted the design to be more generic. With the following basic setup:

```
package First;
use Moose;
use Second::Type1;
use Second::Type2;
has 'type1' => (
  is => 'rw',
  isa => 'Second::Type1',
  default => sub {Second::Type1->new(name => 'random')}
);

has 'type2' => (
  is => 'rw',
  isa => 'Second::Type2',
  default => sub {Second::Type2->new(name => 'random')}
);

package Second::Type1;
use Moose;
use This;
has 'name' => (
  is => 'rw',
  isa => 'Str',
  required => 1,
);
has 'this' => (
  is => 'rw',
  isa => 'This',
  default => sub {This->new()}
);
# package has more attributes, but you get the idea
__PACKAGE__->meta->make_immutable();
no Moose;
1;

package Second::Type2;
use Moose;
use That;
has 'name' => (
  is => 'rw',
  isa => 'Str',
  required => 1,
);
has 'that' => (
  is => 'rw',
  isa => 'That',
  default => sub {That->new()}
);
# package has more attributes, but you get the idea
__PACKAGE__->meta->make_immutable();
no Moose;
1;
```

I want to be able to construct a First by saying:

```
use First;
my $first = First->new(type1 => 'foo', type2 => 'bar');
```

where 'foo' equals the value for Second::Type1's 'name' attribute and 'bar' equals the value for Second::Type2's 'name' attribute.

Now as to my own solution, I've (successfully) made a Moose::Role which only contains an 'around BUILDARGS' sub and then using a Factory class (the contents of which aren't relevant here IMO):

```
package Role::SingleBuildargs;

use Moose::Role;
use Factory::Second;
requires 'get_supported_args';

around BUILDARGS => sub {
my ($class, $self, %args) = @_;
my @supported_args = $self->get_supported_args;
my $factory = Factory::Second->new();
    my @errors = ();
    foreach my $arg (sort {$a cmp $b} keys %args) {
        if (grep {$_ eq $arg} @supported_args) {
            my $val = $args{$arg};
            if (!ref $val) {    # passed scalar init_arg
                print "$self (BUILDARGS): passed scalar\n";
                print "Building a Second with type '$arg' and name '$val'\n";
                $args{$arg} = $factory->create(type => $arg, name => $val)
            } elsif (ref $val eq 'HASH') {  # passed hashref init_arg
                print "$self (BUILDARGS): passed hashref:\n";
                my %init_args = %$val;
                delete $init_args{name} unless $init_args{name};
                $init_args{type} = $arg;
                $args{$arg} = $factory->create(%init_args);
            } else {    # passed another ref entirely
                print "$self (BUILDARGS): cannot handle reference of type: ", ref $val, "\n";
                die;
            }
        } else {
            push @errors, "$self - Unsupported attribute: '$arg'";
        }
    }
    if (@errors) {
        print join("\n", @errors), "\n";
        die;
    }
    return $self->$class(%args);
    };

no Moose;
1;
```

and then I use that Role in the First class and other classes like First.

I've also tried coercing via:

```
package Role::Second::TypeConstraints;
use Moose::Util::TypeConstraints

subtype 'SecondType1', as 'Second::Type1';
subtype 'SecondType2', as 'Second::Type2';
coerce 'SecondType1', from 'Str', via {Second::Type1->new(name => $_};
coerce 'SecondType2', from 'Str', via {Second::Type2->new(name => $_};

no Moose::Util::TypeConstraints;
1;
```

and modified the First package (listing only changes):

```
use Role::Second::TypeConstraints;
has 'type1' => (
   isa => 'SecondType1',
   coerce => 1,
);
has 'type2' => (
   isa => 'SecondType2',
   coerce => 1,
);
```

That, however didn't work. If someone could explain why, that would be great.

As to the actual question: what is the best way to obtain this kind of behaviour in your classes? Is there really no better way than modifying BUILDARGS, or did I miss something (about Moose::Util::TypeConstraints, perhaps)? TMTOWTDI and all, but mine doesn't seem efficient at all.

EDIT: edited for consistency (mixed up generic class names)

Comment: I've done such things in the past using coercion.

Can't see straight off why your existing coercion set-up isn't doing it.

You have remembered what is usually the major stumbling block which is adding the coercion meta attribute to the attributes where you want coercion to happen.

I suggest persevering with coercion.

Comment: This is exactly what `BUILDARGS` is for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do exactly as you describe using coercion

- Add

  ```
  use Moose::Util::TypeConstraints;
  ```

  to `First`, `Second::Type1` and `Second::Type2`
- Add a coercion action to `Second::Type1`

  ```
  coerce 'Second::Type1'
      => from 'Str'
          => via { Second::Type1->new( name => $_ ) };
  ```

  and to `Second::Type2`

  ```
  coerce 'Second::Type2'
      => from 'Str'
          => via { Second::Type2->new( name => $_ ) };
  ```
- Enable coercion for the `type1` and `type2` attributes of `First`

  ```
  has 'type1' => (
    is      => 'rw',
    isa     => 'Second::Type1',
    default => sub { Second::Type1->new },
    coerce  => 1,
  );

  has 'type2' => (
    is      => 'rw',
    isa     => 'Second::Type2',
    default => sub { Second::Type2->new },
    coerce  => 1,
  );
  ```

Then you can create a `First` object exactly as you say, with

```
my $first = First->new(type1 => 'foo', type2 => 'bar');
```

Comment: Your solution seems more elegant than defining a custom type just for the sake of one class, like I did. I'll give it a shot.

Comment: Tried it now. Works like you said. For clarity's sake: "use Moose::Util::TypeConstraints;" also needs to be added to the 'First' package for any coercion to work on its attributes, but I'm sure that was implicit in your post, Borodin.

Comment: @etripe: I'm glad you have a solution. I'd overlooked that modification, thank you. I've added it to my post. By the way I don't think the `default` items are correct, as the constructor needs the `name` attribute to work

Comment: @etripe: I'm not sure it makes sense to have a default at all, especially without any checking for uniqueness. But that depends a lot on the design of your real-world app so it's completely up to you. I guess, with the coercion in place, you could write `default = 'Default Type2'` instead of calling the constructor

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely do it with types and coercion. Try using [MooseX::Types](https://metacpan.org/pod/MooseX::Types) instead of the built-in ones.

Here's a small example, partly lifted from the MooseX::Types docs.

```
package Foo;
use Moose;
use MooseX::Types -declare => [qw(MyDateTime)];
use MooseX::Types::Moose 'Int';
use DateTime;

class_type MyDateTime, { class => 'DateTime' };
coerce MyDateTime, from Int, via { DateTime->from_epoch( epoch => $_ ) };

has date => (
    is      => 'ro',
    isa     => MyDateTime,
    default => sub {time},
    coerce  => 1,
);

package main;

my $foo = Foo->new;
say 'without args: ', $foo->date;

my $bar = Foo->new( date => time - 24 * 3600 );
say 'with args:    ', $bar->date;
```

This will print something like:

```
without args: 2015-06-26T13:35:38
with args:    2015-06-25T13:35:38
```

It looks a lot like what you have, just using the newer type thing. Give it a try.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'll look into what you said. I'll also have a look at the documentation to see what I gain by using MooseX::Types over the usual Moose::Util::TypeConstraints.